# How to convert a luajit pointer to a string and back?

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit, lua-lanes

I need some help converting a luajit pointer to a string and back.

First I define the ctype:

```
ffi.cdef[[
    typedef struct {
        unsigned char Bytes[16];
    } EncryptionKeys[100000000];

void* malloc(size_t);                   
void free(void*);
]]
```

Then use malloc to allocate some memory and then create the 'EncryptionKeys' variable.

```
local EncryptionKeyMemoryAddress = ffi.C.malloc(ffi.sizeof("EncryptionKeys"))

local EncryptionKeys = ffi.cast("EncryptionKeys(&)", EncryptionKeyMemoryAddress)
```

I first convert the variable into a lua string using:

```
ffi.string(EncryptionKeyMemoryAddress)
```

But I can't figure out how to convert it back!
Can someone please help me?

FYI: I am passing the 'EncryptionKeyMemoryAddress' variable to one of the function parameters for a lua lane (https://lualanes.github.io/lanes/).

**Edit**:
Here is the section of code that I am working on:
This is for the client managers module of my server that manages a list of lua states that all have access to any clients connected to the server. They all use a shared section of memory that I want them to have access to using a pointer.

```
local ClientFFIString = [[
    
    typedef struct {
        unsigned char Bytes[16];
    } EncryptionKeys[100000000];

    void* malloc(size_t);                   
    void free(void*);
]]

ffi.cdef(Matchpools.FFIString)

local EncryptionKeyMemoryAddress = ffi.C.malloc(ffi.sizeof("EncryptionKeys"))

--------------------------------------------
function ClientManagers.CreateNewClientManager()

    local EncryptionKeys = ffi.cast("EncryptionKeys(&)", EncryptionKeyMemoryAddress)

    EncryptionKeys[0].Bytes[0] = 24

    print("___a", EncryptionKeys[0].Bytes[0])


    local NewIndex = #ClientManagers.List+1
    ClientManagers.List[NewIndex] = ClientManagerFunc(
        ClientFFIString, 
        ffi.string(EncryptionKeysMemoryAddress)
    )

end


--------------------------------------------
local ClientManagerFunc = Lanes.gen("*", function(ClientFFIString, EncryptionKeysMemoryAddress)

    ffi = require("ffi")

    ffi.cdef(ClientFFIString)


    local EncryptionKeys = ffi.cast("EncryptionKeys(&)", EncryptionKeyMemoryAddress)
    
    print("___a", EncryptionKeys[0].Bytes[0]) 
    -- I want this to be 24 just like it is in the function that created this lua state


    local ClientManagerRunning = true
    while ClientManagerRunning do

        --local dt = GetDt()

        --UpdateClientData(dt)

        --UpdateMatchmaking(dt)

    end

end)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert it back"? Do you mean "copy it back"? Because my understanding is that `ffi.string` creates a copy of the binary data. And are you sure you want to copy 1.5GB of data?

Comment: I have 2 different lua states that I want to use the same section of memory on my server. I want to give them both the pointer to that section of memory so they both can use it. I only want to pass the pointer to the memory as a lua string (not copy it). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert Lua string to your structure pointer (and later use it as an array):

```
ffi.cdef"typedef struct {unsigned char Bytes[16];} Key;"
ptr=ffi.cast("Key *", your_string)
print("First Byte of the First Key in your Array:", ptr[0].Bytes[0])
```

**UPDATE:**
Let's test how it works for an array containing three keys:

```
local ffi = require'ffi'
ffi.cdef"typedef struct {unsigned char Bytes[16];} Key;"
local your_string = string.char(11):rep(16)..string.char(22):rep(16)..string.char(33):rep(16)
local ptr=ffi.cast("Key *", your_string)
print("First Byte of the First Key in your Array:", ptr[0].Bytes[0])
print("First Byte of the Second Key in your Array:", ptr[1].Bytes[0])
print("First Byte of the Third Key in your Array:", ptr[2].Bytes[0])
```

It prints 11, 22, 33

---

**UPDATE 2**:
Pass the address of buffer instead of the content of buffer

In the main thread

```
-- allocate the buffer
local Keys = ffi.cast("EncryptionKeys&", ffi.C.malloc(ffi.sizeof("EncryptionKeys")))
-- write to the buffer
Keys[2].Bytes[5] = 42
-- create string containing 64-bit address
local string_to_send = tostring(ffi.cast("uint64_t", Keys))
-- Send string_to_send to a lane
```

Inside the lane

```
-- receive the string
local received_string = .....
-- restore the buffer pointer
local Keys = ffi.cast("EncryptionKeys&", loadstring("return "..received_string)())
-- read the data from the buffer
print(Keys[2].Bytes[5])
```

Comment: When I try to apply this to my code I get the error message (ClientManagers.lua:147: 'struct 128 [100000000]' has no member named 'Bytes'). Maybe I am doing something wrong with pointers?

Comment: Show your line #147.  Please note that `EncryptionKeys` is incompatible with `Key`.  You should use `EncryptionKeys` when converting to string and use `Key` when converting from string.

Comment: Okay I understand now. This worked thank you!

Comment: Please note that while you are working with `ptr[x].Bytes[y]` values the original Lua string `your_string` must stay anchored in Lua (for example, in a local variable) to avoid being garbage collected, because you are actually reading the content of this string.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again.

Comment: This solution actually only works for ptr[0]. Any indexes over that do not work. Do you know why and how I can fix that?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem.  It works fine for me.  The answer is updated with a code for testing.  Can you post your code which fails?

Comment: When I try your solution it works fine until I pass your_string into the lua lane and initialize the array inside the lane. Then the array does not access values above 0. Maybe I stated the question wrong. Basically I need to transfer the pointer of a memory location (EncryptionKeyMemoryAddress which is returned by malloc) to a lua lane so that I can access the data from inside the lua lane. I want to pass the 8 byte pointer not the actual data and use that. Think of multiple lua states having access to the same location of memory concurrently.

Comment: Converting from address to array is almost the same.  What cdata object does contain the address?  How did you define it inside cdef?  Is it `int64_t` / `void *` / something else ?

Comment: In other words, what is the output of `print(type(your_string), ffi.typeof(your_string))` inside a lane?

Comment: Printing inside of the lane throws an error, but printing outside of the lane results in: 'cdata,    ctype<void *>'  I am passing the result of malloc as the 'your_string' variable so I am pretty sure it is an 8 byte pointer.

Comment: Yes the address is contained in 'void*' This is malloc in my cdef: ```void* malloc(size_t);```

Comment: Ok, outside a lane you have `void *` from malloc, and you pass it to a lane.  But what value does the lane receive?  `print(type(value))`

Comment: type inside the lane is 'string'

Comment: So, you should ask a new question "How to pass a string to lua-lane" (and set corresponding tag to call for users with lua-lanes experience).  Or (probably) you can simply read the lua-lanes docs.

Comment: Okay I am going to ask a new question. I just tried to get the length of the string outside of the lane and it was zero also. Could it have to do with using the (&) operator for malloc instead of * ? ```ffi.C.malloc(ffi.sizeof("EncryptionKeys(&)"))```

Comment: See update 2. It contains an example how to pass address of buffer.

Comment: Thanks alot Egor :).